# Expanded ListView not working inside of TabBarView

Tags: flutter

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to acheive.

[image]

However I want both lists in the TabBarView to expand to the bottom of the screen. The only way I can get it to work now, is with a Container with a fixed height. If I use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`, then it expands off the bottom of the page and I get the yellow black overflow thing.

If I wrap the `TabBarView` in an `Expanded` widget instead of the fixed size `Container`, I get a `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.` error. If I wrap each `ListView` in `Expanded` (while the fixed height Container is removed), I get a `Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.` error. Any idea what I should try next?

Here's the code.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, top: 6),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
              child: const Text('Home'),
            ),
            DefaultTabController(
              length: 2,
              initialIndex: 0,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: TabBar(
                      isScrollable: true,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(text: 'Subscriptions'),
                        Tab(text: 'Recently Visited'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 500,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                            top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))),
                    child: TabBarView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        buildAList(),
                        buildAList()
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildAList() {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: List<Widget>.generate(
        100,
        (i) => Text(
          'Item $i',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I changed in the code below is I wrapped your `TabBarView`'s `Container` widget with an `Expanded` widget and then wrapped the `DefaultTabController` with another `Expanded` widget. If you're going to put an `Expanded` widget somewhere, you should probably wrap it's parent with an `Expanded` widget too if it's inside of a flexible widget such as a `Row` or `Column`.

I also changed your `buildAList` function to use a `ListView.builder` so that you didn't have to "generate" a list.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, top: 6),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
              child: const Text('Home'),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: DefaultTabController(
                length: 2,
                initialIndex: 0,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: TabBar(
                        isScrollable: true,
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(text: 'Subscriptions'),
                          Tab(text: 'Recently Visited'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: TabBarView(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            buildAList(),
                            buildAList(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildAList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (c, i) {
        return Text(
          "Item $i",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: This achevied what I was looking for. Thank you so much! I have used `Expanded` before the solve similar issues, so I was so confused why it didn't work this time, but I didn't think to wrap the whole `DefaultTabController` in an `Expanded` widget too. Thanks!